# Dimension of $\dim_{\mathbb C}\mathbb C[X,Y]/I(Y^2-X^2,Y^2+X^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to solve the question 1.36 from Fulton's algebraic curves book:

> Let $I=(Y^2-X^2,Y^2+X^2)\subset\mathbb C[X,Y]$. Find $V(I)$ and
>   $\dim_{\mathbb C}\mathbb C[X,Y]/I$.

Obviously $V(I)=\{(0,0)\}$ and by a corolary in the same section we know that $\dim_{\mathbb C}(\mathbb C[X,Y]/I)\lt \infty$, but I don't know how to calculate $\dim_{\mathbb C}(\mathbb C[X,Y]/I)$.

I need help in this part.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @900sit-upsaday is it ok now?

Comment: You’re intersecting two sets in the plane, each of degree two. You should *hope* that there are four points of intersection, counting multiplicity, and that should be the same as the $\mathbb C$-dimension of your quotient ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a ring $R$, every element of $R[x]$ is a sum of elements $a_0+a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots +a_n x^n$ where $a_i \in R$.  Using this twice, we have that a basis for $\mathbb C[x,y]$ is the monomials $x^iy^j$ where $i,j\in \mathbb N$  Since $I=(x^2+y^2,x^2-y^2)=(x^2,y^2)$, we have that every monomial where either $i$ or $j$ is at least $2$ will be in $I$, and so every element of $\mathbb C[x,y]/I$ is of the form $a + bx + cy + dxy +I$.  In fact, the elements of $I$ are spanned by the monomials where either $i$ or $j$ are at least $2$, and so $\{1,x,y,xy\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb C[x,y]/I$, and so the dimension is $4$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have one question: why $\{1,x,y,xy\}$ is linearly independent?

Comment: Assuming that you agree they are linearly independent in $\mathbb C[x,y]$, it is because otherwise we would have an expression out of them in $I$, but this can't happen because every element of $I$ is a linear combination of things with either higher powers of $x$ or higher powers of $y$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $Y^2=\bigl((Y^2-X^2)+(Y^2+X^2)\bigr)/2$ belongs to $I$, which in turn implies that $X^2=(Y^2+X^2)-Y^2\in I$. In other words $(X^2,Y^2)\subseteq I$, and a similar reasoning shows the reversed inclusion. Having this, what can you say about the higher order terms of an arbitrary polynomial modulo $I$?

Comment: I've already proven $I=(X^2,Y^2)$, but what can I do with this result to prove the question?

Comment: @user42912 You can't find a $\Bbb C$-basis for $\Bbb C[X,Y]/(X^2,Y^2)$?

Comment: @blue No, I'm sorry, can you help me? thanks

Comment: @user42912, Do you know a basis of $C[X,Y]$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez No, I have problems to know basis of polynomial rings.